# SQL query data before, during and after campaign

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have some website data that shows impressions and clicks for a product ID per day.  The table also has a column that shows if the product is currently included in a 7 day campaign.  I want to get the impressions and clicks 7 days before, during (7 days) and 7 days after the campaign.

The data I currently have looks like:

```
|ID  |Date    |Campaign|type |imps|clicks|
|1001|20190101|No      |image|100 |1     |
|1001|20190102|Yes     |video|100 |5     |
```

It shows the clicks and impressions per day,per ID and split by to dims Campaign and Type.

A campaign lasts for 7 days where the Campaign column will switch from No to yes for 7 days.

I want a new column called 'campaign period' which is before,during or after.

For simplicity I want to look at products in one month +/- 7 days.

Finally I want to group by campaign period and type to calculate CTR.

The code I currently have is a simple group by and sum of imps and clicks however I am unure how to do a before/during/after split:

```
SELECT 
 Campaign,
 type, 
 SUM(imps), 
 SUM(clicks)
FROM table
GROUP BY 
 Campaign, 
 type
```

The final results should look like:

```
|Campaign Period|Type |Imps|Clicks|
|Before         |Image|20  |2     |
|After          |Video|30  |5     |
...
```

I am looking to create the Campaign Period column

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: The expected result doesn't seem to match the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You should treat it as different queries and then join them:

This query will give you the total for the days BEFORE the campaign

```
  SELECT Campaign, type,  SUM(imps),  SUM(clicks)
    FROM table
   WHERE Campaign='No'
     AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT id
                      FROM table AS t2
                     WHERE t2.Campaign='yes'
                       AND t2.type = table.type
                       AND t2.Date < table.Date
                   )
GROUP BY Id, type
```

This query will give you the total for the days IN the campaign

```
  SELECT Campaign, type,  SUM(imps),  SUM(clicks)
    FROM table
   WHERE Campaign='Yes'
GROUP BY Id, type
```

This query will give you the total for the days AFTER the campaign

```
  SELECT Campaign, type,  SUM(imps),  SUM(clicks)
    FROM table
   WHERE Campaign='No'
     AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT id
                      FROM table AS t2
                     WHERE t2.Campaign='yes'
                       AND t2.type = table.type
                       AND t2.Date > table.Date
                   )
GROUP BY Id, type
```

Now, simply join all three queries and you'll have your expected result.

Comment: This does work however I need to be able to only look at 7 days before and after.  The table I am querying has a years worth of data.  These queries look at everything.  For example I would like to specify a date range of 1 month (july for example) and get 7 days before,during and after for each ID.  If a ID started the campaign on the 1st then the before will cut into the month before and if the campaign for the ID starts on the 30th the after will cut into August.

Comment: Well, then you should add a condition on each query. I'll update the answer